# Does the sentence: "While common credence..." make sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, phrase-requests

If I want to argue against something commonly accepted to be true, can I say:

> While common credence dictates that eight hours of uninterrupted sleep is absolutely essential, recent studies have shown that sleeping less and more often is more beneficial.

Does the structure "While common credence dictates...it is actually..." make sense?

Because, all the example uses I have seen of the word "credence" seem to make it appear like it isn't something that is *owned* by someone (like common sense, which is what I'm after,) but rather it is something that an idea/theory has.

Is there a better word/phrase I can use? Or does this one after all make sense?

Comment: It's just an obnoxious word for "belief".  If you want another word consult a thesaurus.

Comment: If "common sense" can dictate, and "common decency" can dictate, then why shouldn't "common credence" be able to dictate?

Comment: "While the expert opinion is that..."

Comment: @mahmudkoya originally I had "common opinion," i want it to convey "of the masses" rather than "of the experts."

Comment: Then, *while the common opinion/belief is that...* won't be OK?

Comment: "Common credence dictates" strikes me as just a pompous way to say "Most people think".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the word that should come out is "dictate" rather than credence.

> credence
>  a. Acceptance as true or valid; belief: I wouldn't put
>   too much credence in that story. See Synonyms at belief.
>  [American
>   Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/credence)

So better to have "While common credence is that eight hours..."

If you don't want to use "credence", you can use either:
conventional wisdom
or
popular belief

> While 'conventional wisdom'/'popular belief' *is* that eight hours of uninterrupted sleep is
>   absolutely essential, recent studies have shown that sleeping less and
>   more often is more beneficial.

> conventional wisdom
>  A generally accepted theory or belief.
>   [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conventional_wisdom)
>
> the generally accepted belief, opinion, judgment, or prediction about
>   a particular matter
>  [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conventional%20wisdom)

"Contrary to popular belief" is a common expression. "Popular opinion" by itself didn't seem to give results from many dictionaries, however "Contrary to popular belief" has at least the following dictionaries giving its definition

[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/contrary-to-popular-belief)
[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://Merriam-Webster%20Dictionary)
[thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/contrary+to+popular+belief)

Links to Wikipedia articles on both:
[Conventional wisdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_wisdom)

[Popular belief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popular_belief)

Answer (score 0):

I think ***accepted belief*** or ***folk wisdom*** might fit here, although the word *dictate* would probably be better replaced by *has it that, maintains that* or *suggests.*

I did a search for *common credence* in Sketch Engine's 20 billion-word EnTenTen corpus (a cleaned up web corpus) and in the British National Corpus.  Neither showed even a single occurrence of this collocation.

Other than the fact that it is not familiar usage and that there are alternatives available, I can't see anything wrong with it. But if you do use it I suggest you do so with one of the alternatives to *dictate,* which seems too strong to me for the meaning you have specified.

[Sketch Engine](https://the.sketchengine.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

"Credence" is now pretty much exclusively used in the phrase "give/lend credence to", meaning "to provide evidence that something is true".  Even there it's (IMO) a bit cliched.  I'd avoid it altogether.